# How can I print the text inside the specific nodes in resx file using XmlDocument methods?

Tags: c#, xml, file, xmldocument

I have this **RESX** file and I want to print the text thats inside the **value** **node** **inside the resheader node** and I want to also print a **text from the value inside the data node** into the console , how would I do that inside c# ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Users>
  <resheader name="user">
    <value>jacob</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="platform">
    <value>PC</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="pctype">
    <value>gaming</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="budget">
    <value>1000$</value>
  </resheader>
  <data name="versionpc">
    <value>version xxxx</value>
  </data>
  <data name ="storage">
    <value>1 tb </value>
  </data>
</Users>
```

Comment: What is your desired output? please add it to your question. What did you try? What worked, what didn't?

Answer (score 0):

Read your RESX file like you would read an ordinary XML file :

- http://csharp.net-informations.com/xml/how-to-read-xml.htm

Also, you can query the nodes using XPATH :

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=net-7.0
- https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp